# Jooq JsonObject Select All Statement

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jooq

```
context.select(
            jsonObject(
                    key("id").value(CHAPTER.ID),
                    key("name").value(CHAPTER.NAME),
                    key("createdAt").value(CHAPTER.CREATED_AT),
                    key("topics").value(
                            jsonArrayAgg(
                                    jsonObject(
                                            key("id").value(TOPIC.ID),
                                            key("name").value(TOPIC.NAME),
                                            key("createdAt").value(TOPIC.CREATED_AT),
                                              )
                                        )
                                       )

                      )
                                          )
            .from(CHAPTER)
            .join(TOPIC)
            .on(CHAPTER.ID.eq(TOPIC.CHAPTER_ID))
            .fetch().into(Chapter.class);
```

When I implement the above jooq statement it working file .
In the select statement I have to specify all the columns of the table if no they are not being loaded in the result.
Is there any simple way to select all the columns in the table instead of writing each and every "key().value()" pair for every column while using the join in the jooq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`jsonObject(Field...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#jsonObject(org.jooq.Field...)) overload, and use that as such:

```java
jsonObject(MY_TABLE.fields())
```

It will produce the field name as a JSON object key, which doesn't seem to be exactly what you want, you seem to want to use a camel case notation. You can still do that dynamically, using this approach:

```java
jsonObject(Arrays
    .stream(MY_TABLE.fields())
    .map(f -> key(toCamelCase(f.getName())).value(f))
    .toList()
)
```

All you have to do is implement the `toCamelCase()` auxiliary method, or use one from the `java.beans` module, or from Spring, etc.

Comment: It is working if I want to get the fields of only one Table. For example, from your solution, I got the Chapter tables id, name, createdAt fields but 'topics' is not a field in the chapter table. So how do I add it after using Arrays.stream(..).. ?

Comment: @SaiUttej: Many roads lead to rome. `Stream.concat` is one of them